# Printing the values on the trendline in the time series chart to the console at GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I print the values above the trendline in the time series chart to the console? For example, I want to print the first and last number on the trendline to the console.

Code Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Formserdar%2Fdefault%3Agis_stack

```
var startTime = '2000-01-01';
var endTime = '2016-01-01';


// x The polygon that describes the plot.
var plot = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[28.51818846650565, 38.69338161384325],
          [28.518188466504512, 38.6927510390996],
          [28.5189930726267, 38.69275103633082],
          [28.518993072625108, 38.693381611074464],
          [28.51818846650565, 38.69338161384325]]]);



//Add Map layers

var dot = ui.Map.Layer(plot, {color: 'FF0000'});
  Map.layers().set(1, dot);
  Map.centerObject(plot);
  Map.setOptions('satellite');

//-----------------------------CHARTS-------------------------------

//Landsat 7 32-Day NDVI Composite
var landsat7MonthlyNdvi = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI').filterDate(startTime, endTime).select('NDVI');
var landsat7MonthlyTimeSeries = Chart.image.series(landsat7MonthlyNdvi, plot, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30);
landsat7MonthlyTimeSeries = landsat7MonthlyTimeSeries
    .setOptions({
        title: 'Landsat 7 32-Day Monthly NDVI Composite',
        hAxis: {title: 'Date', gridlines: {count: 10}},
        vAxis: {title: 'NDVI',viewWindowMode: 'explicit', viewWindow: {max: 1,min: -0.25,},gridlines: {count: 5,}},
        interpolateNulls: true, 
        lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 1,
    crosshair: { trigger: "both", orientation: "both", color: 'green' },
    trendlines: { 0: {type:'linear', showR2: true, lineWidth:2, pointSize: 0, color:'red', visibleInLegend: true}}
    });
    
print(landsat7MonthlyTimeSeries, landsat7MonthlyNdvi);
```